# Migration of default BIO_METHOD from OpenSSL 1.0.2 to 1.1.1

Tags: c, openssl

I'm trying to port my application code from OpenSSL 1.0.2 to 1.1.1 and I came across a change I can't seem to understand.

In 1.0.2 we have replaced the default `bread` and `bwrite` methods of `BIO_s_socket` by calling:

```
orig_bread = BIO_s_socket()->bread;
orig_bwrite = BIO_s_socket()->bwrite;
BIO_s_socket()->bread = my_bread;
BIO_s_socket()->bwrite = my_bwrite;
```

However, in OpenSSL 1.1.1 `BIO_s_socket()` is said to return `const BIO_METHOD*` instead of `BIO_METHOD*`. How can I change the default behavior in this version?

Edit: (...and if can't do it anymore, how do I set a bread and bwrite per ssl connection?)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to port my application code from OpenSSL 1.0.2 to 1.1.0

Firstly I recommend you move to 1.1.1 not 1.1.0. 1.1.1 is a Long Term Support version (LTS) and will be supported until 2023. 1.1.0 support ends later this year.

You need to create a custom BIO_METHOD. In brief you create one using `BIO_meth_new()` and then set custom read and write functions using `BIO_meth_set_read()` and `BIO_meth_set_write()`. Depending on what your BIO_METHOD does you may need to call other set functions. They are all documented here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/BIO_meth_new.html

Comment: That's the easy part. How do I set it as the default BIO_METHOD like in my original code?

Comment: You cannot change the default BIO_METHOD returned by BIO_s_socket(). You just need to ensure that wherever you call BIO_s_socket() in your code now, you replace it with some function that returns your newly created custom BIO_METHOD. If you never do this, because you are using SSL_set_fd/SSL_set_wfd/SSL_set_rfd to set a file descriptor directly into the SSL object then swap instead to using SSL_set0_rbio() and SSL_set0_wbio().